# Is it possible to run Devuan Ascii with OpenRC init?

Tags: sysvinit, openrc, devuan

I have Devuan Ascii with SysVinit installed. I see that the openRC version is much older in Devuan ascii repository. Has anyone tried Devuan with openRC? Is the parallel starts enabled for openRC?

Comment: Have a look at Antix

Comment: Yeah. I should try. But, does antiX has packaged openRC and other packages to work without systemd.

Comment: Antix has made a much better job of avoiding systemd than Devuan. As for openRC no idea. Flooded on work today, wont be able to check that out for you.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will try to boot an antiX iso (default is runit init, I guess) to see.

Comment: Antix has openrc, just checked, no systemd.

Answer (score 6):

### tl;dr

Yes, it can be, but **it is slower and less efficient than the default sysvinit setup**.

### The Default (sysvinit)

A default Devuan Ascii installation already does parallel bootup with [insserv](http://www.man.he.net/man8/insserv) and [startpar](http://man.he.net/man8/startpar). These work by parsing LSB headers in initscripts (take a look inside `/etc/init.d`) that explicitly specify dependencies. When you run `sudo insserv`, `insserv` processes these init scripts into files such as `/etc/init.d/.depend.boot`, `/etc/init.d/.depend.start`, etc. On bootup, `startpar` reads these scripts and starts processes in parallel according to these rules.

For example, here is my bootchart with sysvinit (booting to a console):
[image: sysv bootchart]

### OpenRC (unoptimized)

Installing OpenRC is done like any other package:

```
$ apt update
$ apt install openrc
```

After installation, it will tell you:

```
**********************************************************************
*** WARNING: if you are replacing sysv-rc by OpenRC, then you must ***
*** reboot immediately using the following command:                ***
for file in /etc/rc0.d/K*; do s=`basename $(readlink "$file")` ; /etc/init.d/$s stop; done
**********************************************************************
```

Run that as superuser.

In the process of installation, `apt` will remove `insserv` and `startpar`.

However, at least in my experience, **OpenRC is slower than augmented sysvinit** due to the fact that OpenRC calculates dependencies at boot time, as opposed to `insserv` which does so at package-install time.

For example, here is my bootchart with OpenRC, which is 1.57 seconds slower:
[image: openrc unoptimized bootchart]

### OpenRC (optimized)

If we want to go further, we can add the line `rc_parallel="YES"` to `/etc/rc.conf`. However, this mangles the startup output for a minimal gain in startup time, which is still slower than `insserv`+`startpar`:
[image: openrc optimized bootchart]

This is because OpenRC is still using the LSB init scripts written in shell, as opposed to setups more optimized for it using openrc-run. Even with an updated version of OpenRC with openrc-init used instead of sysvinit, the bootup times are still worse.